# cursor sql query on Spring environment

Tags: java, sql, spring, postgresql, jdbc

We are getting Out of Memory exceptions on JDBC driver when accesing postgresql DB from java, on queries with over a million rows.
We are in a Spring environment and use

```
entityManager.createNativeQuery(
```

for direct queries to DB.
We have tried `OPEN cursor FOR EXECUTE ...your query here..."` to create postgresql cursors into the DB, but is not working.
We know that we need native DB cursors to retrieve results without memory problems, what's the best way to do it?

Comment: A cursor won't work either as long as you, in the end, receive everything in memory in a collection you will run out of memory. It isn't the `createNativeQuery` that is the issue. It is the `getResultList` call in the end. If you have a newer JPA implementation you can do `getResultStream` and get a stream which is a cursor and load records 1 by 1.

Comment: in our case we got out of memory on the JDBC driver. A JDBC cursor fix this, and you are rigth, only pospone the problem, if you acumulate all data on a java structure you get out of memory there. The solution was to process cursor data on another thread, with a Consumer class that write streamed data on disk, using POI for excel production in our use case.  I didn't know about getResultStream and JPA cursor, I'll ckeck it, but our solution with JDBC cursor works ok.

Answer (score 0):

The way to go are cursors managed by JDBC, as explained [here](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/query.html#query-with-cursor).
For that, you need a plain JDBC connection from Spring pool, and to get that in Spring the best way is this:

```
@Autowired 
private DataSource dataSource;
Connection conn = DataSourceUtils.getConnection(dataSource);
```